# out-of-the-box javascript tool to create a visual tree from a json format

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, tree

I am looking for an out of the box javascript code that generates a VISUAL tree out of a JSON.

I found A LOT of online tools that do that, but non of them share their code, and i need to use it in my application. I don't want to use a platform that limits me to certain attribute names or building another model of a tree.

In short, I need THE CODE for something like one of the next online examples, and don't want to write it myself, before I really check if it already exists.

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

http://jsontree.com/

Comment: This could be what you're looking for. The code is posted on the bottom. http://joncom.be/code/javascript-json-formatter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the best thing i could find:

http://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

very helpful and easy package.